# Add info window to each marker

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I have successfully added multiple markers to a Google map and now I want to add an info window to each marker. I've tried multiple ways with no luck.

What I would like if for an info window with the `property_title` to popup when the marker is clicked on.

Here is what I have so far.

```
var data = 

{ "property": [
{"property_id": 1, "property_title": "property 1", "property_img": "imag1", "longitude": 1234, "latitude": 1234, "width": 500, "height": 375},
{"property_id": 2, "property_title": "property 2", "property_img": "imag1", "longitude": 1234, "latitude": 1234, "width": 500, "height": 375},
{"property_id": 3, "property_title": "property 3", "property_img": "imag1", "longitude": 1234, "latitude": 1234, "width": 500, "height": 375},
{"property_id": 4, "property_title": "property 4", "property_img": "imag1", "longitude": 1234, "latitude": 1234, "width": 500, "height": 375},
{"property_id": 5, "property_title": "property 5", "property_img": "imag1", "longitude": 1234, "latitude": 1234, "width": 500, "height": 375}
]};             

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var dataProperty = data.property[i];
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataProperty.latitude,
          dataProperty.longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the working demo below.

http://jsfiddle.net/RJPKJ/1/

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){                       
var dataProperty = dataitem.property[i];     
latitudetest =dataProperty.latitude;
longitudetest = dataProperty.longitude;
var data= dataProperty.property_title;    
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudetest, longitudetest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. If you're not up to this task, you should consider simply [leaving a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on the question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: the link itself is the actual answer I think.

Comment: As per the discussion linked above - "you haven't answered their question at all, you've deferred the answering to somewhere else". "When someone goes on StackOverflow, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer." If the code in the link would answer OP's question, you should post it, or preferably just the required part of it, or better yet, OP's code modified to do what was asked, ideally along with an explanation of both what the code does and why OP's code doesn't work.